# Building a charger for a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, charger

I have a 5V DC supply that outputs at most 1.5A, and I want to charge a 25F capacitor (BCAP0025-T01) at 2.5V and close to 1.5A.

How can I build a circuit to achieve this? Current mirror maybe?

Apologies if this is lacking in information. Feel free to make assumptions and throw out ideas; I'll be happy to do further research given some leads.

Comment: what does your supply do if you try to draw more than 1.5A? Does it shut down, deliver constant current, deliver reduced current, blow up?

Comment: Just consider it the same way you would charge a tiny battery except your asbsolute maximum limits are 2.85 V and 
Absolute Maximum Current 20 A . THis can be efficient performed in a SMPS buck regulator design that can supply current limited to 2.5 to 3A with an inrush limit of 1.5A and stop at 2.7 to  2.8V.

Comment: What is your design skill level? What limitiations do you have for parts?

Comment: Neil_UK: I believe it shuts off at >1.5A

Tony: Quite novice. I have access to some basic op amps (LM741, LM324), smalltransistors and some power transistors, resistors/caps (no inductors).

Comment: I think a series resistor and the supply should be sufficient to charge the capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

A current mirror is useless for this purpose.

Have a look at [Julian Ilett's channel on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/julius256)

He likes to do stuff with supercapacitors and has several videos on the subject.

In general he uses an adjustable power supply module with adjustable current limit. He uses a powerful one which will be overkill for your problem.

I would use a module [like this](https://www.ebay.nl/itm/DC-DC-LM2596-Step-down-Adjustable-CC-CV-Power-Supply-Module-LED-driver/141666333732?hash=item20fbf8b424:g:oqEAAOSwpDdVVJxf). Which can convert 5 V into 2.5 V and where the maximum current can also be set.

[image]

Since this is a switching regulator you can even charge with a higher current at the output, up to 2.5 A or so, without overloading the 5 V 1.5 A supply.